# ZBAR android ARM 64 couldn't find "libiconv.so"

Tags: android, zbar

On samsung galaxy s6 edge my app crashes when calling the zbar sdk, for scanning. I think it is because I don't have an arm64 version of zbar.

This is the end of the crash log:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/.../base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/.../lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libiconv.so"
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
```

I seen in my project that i don't have arm64 jni libs for zbar
is this related ? 
and if so where can i get 
`libiconv.so`
`libzbarjni.so`
for arm64 ?

Comment: Hi @Noam. Have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: yes see my answer below

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I decided to move to ZXing instead, which works with Galaxy S3 Edge

Comment: Zxing has its caveats to. Modifying its ui

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So finally found the zbar 64 bit from here:

https://github.com/SkillCollege/ZBarAndroidSDK/tree/master/ZBarScanProjAll/libs

it is found under arm64-v8a. All i had to do is rename the so file to match my project.

Comment: How did you find the libzbarjni.so?

Comment: In the link above it is called something libzbardecoder just copy it and rename it according to your project

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded iconv.so and libZBarDecoder.so in arm64-v8a.

- Rename `libZBarDecoder.so` to `libzbarjni.so`
- Zip file and rename it to *iconv.jar* (because
  "System.loadLibrary("iconv") in my project").

And finally it work. Thanks Noam Segev.

https://github.com/SkillCollege/ZBarAndroidSDK/tree/master/ZBarScanProjAll/libs

Comment: Hey! I've downloaded both files. Let me know if I got it right -  I need to rename both files as you suggested, and then Zip both and change the name to iconv.jar ? (it's called "iconv" in my project as well).

Answer (score 2):

For `libiconv`

Grab the libiconv source, and make an Android.mk makefile. Look at this site (http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/012d679319e4ea6e?pli=1) for a prewritten makefile for libiconv and Android. Once you have the Android.mk file you can build using the ndk-build script.

For `libzbarjni`

http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/?p=139